# How many days should this test run for getting sufficient sample size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

We are running a live experiment where a debit card's packaging is tested across 5 group of stores (200 stores each) with 5 variants.
We would compare the card sales before the test date (around 30 days), with the card sales post the commencement of the test (30 days) in each of the test groups.
Currently, it is arbitrarily set at 30 days.
Is there a better way to estimate the no of days needed in past and future windows?

Comment: You would need to give us much more information for the question to be answerable.

Comment: Debit cards are sold at stores of a large retail chain. The experiment that we run is to test if packaging of the card has an effect on cards sold. There are 5 variants of the card packages. Currently, we are comparing cards sold 30 days pre test to cards sold 30 days post test and we do this for each of the 5 test groups. The variant with highest % change in cards sold would be the winner. My question was is there a better to way to select the no of days (currently it's 30 day window) b. Is there an alternative to this approach

Comment: please add description to main question. the kind of further questions would be how many card sales per day for each variant (expected). how does time enter into your sales? [eg is there a ramp on period where sales are only expected to pick up 10 days after introduction]. what about calendar effects, do debit card sales pick up in eg november? (ideally you would test in parallel rather than sequentially, and if not at least switch the order between stores)